# rest vs soap what's the difference

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

hey guys wondering if you can help me with a question, what are the differences in defining a service in WCF in comparison to SOAP or REST and what does REST bring that SOAP based services do not?

Comment: WCF supports SOAP as a protocol... are you actually looking for a comparison between WCF and classic ASMX web services?

Answer (score 0):

wcf is the way of microsoft to describe a webservice.
basically it is technology independent.

soap is a technology.

edit: 
soap = protocol
wcf = technology.

so wcf is protocol independent.

Comment: Actually, it would be the other way around: SOAP is a (abstract) **protocol** (the `P` in its name stands for it), while WCF is the **concrete technology** that implements that protocol (and others)

Comment: @Garrith: no, that question really doesn't make any sense at all ....

Comment: yep u're right wcf is the technology, soap is a protocol.just used a wrong terminology